# How do I find the Apple UTI for QGIS?

Tags: macos, uti

I want to configure `duti` to open certain types of file with QGIS, therefore I need to know how to discover an UTI for specific files on macOS.

How can I find the UTI in this case for QGIS?

Comment: I’ve edited this slightly to remove the chit chat. Are you aware that one file can have a one to many mapping of identifiers?

Answer (score 2):

The UTI is listed within the application of QGIS in this case.

You can find the information by opening this file (change to accomodate if you have installed it in a different place or you have a different name for the app):

```
/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Search the file for `UTTypeIdentifier` and you'll find something looking somewhat like this (in this example for Microsoft Word):

```
<key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
<string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
```

In this case the UTI is `com.microsoft.word.doc`.

Note that an application might have multiple `UTTypeIdentifier` entries. In that case, you need to look at the given description and filename extension (they're listed right alongside in the file) in order to choose the right one.

If you're not used to working with the Terminal and configuration files like this, you could use a GUI property list editor for viewing the `plist` file. Many different exist - for example [PlistEdit Pro](https://www.fatcatsoftware.com/plisteditpro/).

Comment: Thanks! There's no `UTypeIdentifer` entry in the file, though there is a `CFBundleIdentifier`. Here's the whole file: https://pastebin.com/raw/ajHVMs46

Comment: They're using the old, deprecated way of listing file types. You can just take the "CFBundleTypeExtensions" value (i.e. the file extension) and use that as input for duti. The bundle identifier identifies the application, not the documents/files. You will need to give the bundle identifier to duti to specify that it is QGIS you want started for the file types you specify.